# Android Adding a smooth screen rotation effect

Tags: android, animation, rotation, screen, orientation

I would like to simulate the iOS screen rotation on my app.
My idea of doing this is using a sreen transition which scales and rotates the screen to fit the new orientation, but I don't know where to use overridePendingTransition in order for the transition to affect the new created activity with the new orientation.
Any ideas where to use overridePendingTransition?

Answer (score 0):

You have to fake it by taking a screenshot and animating that. The entire `Activity` is destroyed and recreated and it abruptly blanks out and reappears when you rotate the screen. Otherwise you have to handle the configuration change manually and handle the entire layout change yourself.

iOS smoothly resizes all the UI elements to fit the new dimensions when you rotate it.